# Negative condition in where clause alerted by CodeProfiler

Tags: where-clause, abap, opensql

I checked with CodeProfiler one ABAP report and I received one message regarding the negative condition in the where clause.

I don't know how I should avoid '<>' clause from where condition. I tried to remove condition from the field `augbl` and after SELECT statement delete unnecessary records, but I received a dump `tsv_tnew_page_alloc_failed`.

My idea was to find a pragma expression to skip the CodeProfiler check, but I didn't find anything.

Can you help me with pragma expression or another solution? Thank you in advance!

Source code:

[image]

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: If you remove lines from `lt_step2` which have `klaeb` and `opbel` empty, you may remove the line `AND augbl <> ''` because it can't happen anymore (see I.B.N. answer).

Comment: Where does the table `lt_step2` come from? Does it come from another SELECT? In that case I would see if I can merge those three SELECTs into one using a JOIN.

Comment: Remember that the Code Inspector just provides recommendations. Just because it complains about something does not mean you *must* fix it. Do you actually have a performance problem which affects the user experience? There is no point in spending time on fixing performance problems which don't affect anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
Delete lt_step2 where opbel = ''.
IF lt_step2[] is not initial.
  Select augbl as opbel gpart vkont vtref hvorg tvorg
    into lt_part
    from dfkkop
    for all entries in lt_step2
    where augbl = lt_step2-klaeb.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining how and why this solves the issue.